# Finding the transfer matrix of a system

Tags: matrix, signal-processing, system

I have the following system

[image]

Which represent a system of 4 known inputs with 12 known outputs.

What methods can I use to find the transfer matrix, can I use the neural network or something like that or it is only possible with matrix algebra?

Any help would be appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No need to use neural network, matrix algebra is enough!

- Your question can be formulated as an optimization problem, i.e., `minimize f(T) = norm(y - T*x)` given `y` and `x`. If you have sufficient data pairs `(x,y)`, then you can solve `T`.
- Another easy way is to use [generalized inverse of matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) to solve the transfer matrix `T`, i.e., `T = Y*ginv(X)`. Here I will show you an example in language `R`

```
library(MASS)
Y <- matrix(1:36,nrow = 9)
X <- matrix(1:16,nrow = 4)

T <- Y %*% ginv(X)
```

where

```
> X
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16

> Y
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1   10   19   28
 [2,]    2   11   20   29
 [3,]    3   12   21   30
 [4,]    4   13   22   31
 [5,]    5   14   23   32
 [6,]    6   15   24   33
 [7,]    7   16   25   34
 [8,]    8   17   26   35
 [9,]    9   18   27   36
```

and the transfer `T` is solved as

```
> T
       [,1]  [,2] [,3]   [,4]
 [1,]  1.95 1.025  0.1 -0.825
 [2,]  1.65 0.925  0.2 -0.525
 [3,]  1.35 0.825  0.3 -0.225
 [4,]  1.05 0.725  0.4  0.075
 [5,]  0.75 0.625  0.5  0.375
 [6,]  0.45 0.525  0.6  0.675
 [7,]  0.15 0.425  0.7  0.975
 [8,] -0.15 0.325  0.8  1.275
 [9,] -0.45 0.225  0.9  1.575
```

To verify the obtained `T`, you can use

```
> norm(Y - T%*%X,"2")
[1] 1.178746e-13
```

which is close to `0`, indicating that the obtained `T` is valid.